# Running a command in a Grunt Task

Tags: javascript, templates, gruntjs, continuous-integration, google-closure-compiler

I'm using [Grunt](https://github.com/cowboy/grunt) (task-based command line build tool for JavaScript projects) in my project. I've created a custom tag and I am wondering if it is possible to run a command into it.

To clarify, I'm trying to use Closure Templates and "the task" should call the jar file to pre-compile the Soy file to a javascript file.

I'm running this jar from command line, but I want to set it as a task.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've found a solution so I'd like to share with you.

I'm using grunt under node so, to call terminal commands you need to require 'child_process' module.

For example,

```
var myTerminal = require("child_process").exec,
    commandToBeExecuted = "sh myCommand.sh";

myTerminal(commandToBeExecuted, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (!error) {
         //do something
    }
});
```

Comment: A better approach is to use a plugin (or write your own) to keep your grunt config as config and not code. grunt-shell & grunt-exec are two examples.

Comment: As you use ```sh``` before ```sh mayCommand.sh ``` I'm not sure it would work on windows

Comment: It won't work because it's bash scripting. I'm running under Unix OS's

Answer (score 106):

Alternatively you could load in grunt plugins to help this:

[grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) example:

```
shell: {
  make_directory: {
    command: 'mkdir test'
  }
}
```

or [grunt-exec](https://github.com/jharding/grunt-exec) example:

```
exec: {
  remove_logs: {
    command: 'rm -f *.log'
  },
  list_files: {
    command: 'ls -l **',
    stdout: true
  },
  echo_grunt_version: {
    command: function(grunt) { return 'echo ' + grunt.version; },
    stdout: true
  }
}
```

Comment: Does anyone know if either of those two is usable on Windows?

Comment: I could not immediately get `grunt-shell` to work with Windows+Cygwin but I had better luck with `grunt-exec`.

Comment: Is there a way to use grunt-exec synchronously? It would be nice to chain commands together

Comment: @funseiki just put the commands inside a batch or shell which calls the commands in you preferred order. Or you define task e.g. mycmds and write `"exec:cmd1", "exec:cmd2"` then you also have synchronously order.

Answer (score 37):

Check out `grunt.util.spawn`:

```
grunt.util.spawn({
  cmd: 'rm',
  args: ['-rf', '/tmp'],
}, function done() {
  grunt.log.ok('/tmp deleted');
});
```

Comment: with `opts: {stdio: 'inherit'},` you can see the output of command

Comment: Note: cmd param should be a string not an array.

Comment: This now requires the [`grunt-legacy-util`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-legacy-util) plugin. It recommends using [`require('child_process').spawn()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) instead.

Answer (score 18):

If you are using the latest grunt version (0.4.0rc7 at the time of this writing) both grunt-exec and grunt-shell fail (they don't seem to be updated to handle the latest grunt). On the other hand, child_process's exec is async, which is a hassle.

I ended up using [Jake Trent's solution](http://jaketrent.com/post/impressions-of-grunt/), and adding [shelljs](http://documentup.com/arturadib/shelljs) as a dev dependency on my project so I could just run tests easily and synchronously:

```
var shell = require('shelljs');

...

grunt.registerTask('jquery', "download jquery bundle", function() {
  shell.exec('wget http://jqueryui.com/download/jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.zip');
});
```

Comment: fyi `grunt-shell` is working fine with `grunt v0.4.5` under Windows

Comment: I think using shelljs is a great solution because it enables your node app to access the shell, and it gives you finer control over it than the grunt addons alone.

Answer (score 17):

Guys are pointing child_process, but try to use [execSync](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options) to see output..

```
grunt.registerTask('test', '', function () {
        var exec = require('child_process').execSync;
        var result = exec("phpunit -c phpunit.xml", { encoding: 'utf8' });
        grunt.log.writeln(result);
});
```

Comment: Great solution without any additional plugins.

Comment: I've been trying to get run running tasks for a day, and finally a simple solution that works!

Answer (score 2):

For async shell commands working with Grunt 0.4.x use https://github.com/rma4ok/grunt-bg-shell.