# Why won't Grunt start my express server with Nodemon?

Tags: node.js, express, gruntjs, nodemon

My `Gruntfile` is:

```
module.exports = (grunt) ->
  grunt.initConfig
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON 'package.json'

    concurrent:
      tasks: [
        'nodemon'
      ]

    nodemon:
     dev:
        options:
          script: "server.coffee"
          args: []
          ignoredFiles: ["public/**"]
          watchedExtensions: ["coffee"]
          nodeArgs: ["--debug"]
          delayTime: 1
          env:
            PORT: 9001

          cwd: __dirname

  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt)

  grunt.registerTask 'start', 'concurrent'
```

My `server.coffee` is also super simple:

```
'use strict'

express = require 'express'
winston = require 'winston'

config = require('environmental-configuration')('./config')

app = express()

app.listen config.port
winston.info "App started on port #{config.port}"

module.exports = app
```

But when I do `grunt start`, I get:

```
Running "concurrent:tasks" (concurrent) task

    Running "nodemon:dev" (nodemon) task

Done, without errors.
```

So what am I doing wrong that the server won't start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think grunt doesn't know to call the script configured in `nodemon`, perhaps take a look at [Running a command in a Grunt Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456865/running-a-command-in-a-grunt-task)