# Run a command after a grunt task finishes?

Tags: gruntjs

I want to [run a command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456865/running-a-command-in-a-grunt-task) but ***after*** a task finishes in grunt.

```
uglify: {
    compile: {
        options: {...},
        files: {...}
    }
    ?onFinish?: {
        cmd: 'echo done!',
        // or even just a console.log
        run: function(){
            console.log('done!');
        }
    }
},
```

Either run a command in shell, or even just be able to `console.log`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grunt does not support before and after callbacks, but next version could implement events that would work in the same way, as discussed in [issue #542](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/542).

For now, you should go the task composition way, this is, create tasks for those before and after actions, and group them with a new name:

```
grunt.registerTask('newuglify', ['before:uglify', 'uglify', 'after:uglify']);
```

Then remember to run `newuglify` instead of `uglify`.

Another option is not to group them but remember to add the before and after tasks individually to a queue containing `uglify`:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['randomtask1', 'before:uglify', 'uglify', 'after:uglify', 'randomtask2']);
```

For running commands you can use plugins like [grunt-exec](https://github.com/jharding/grunt-exec) or [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell).

If you only want to print something, try [grunt.log](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.log).

Answer (score 1):

The grunt has one of the horrible code that I've ever seen. I don't know why it is popular. I would never use it even as a joke. This is not related to "legacy code" problem. It is defected by design from the beginning.

```
var old_runTaskFn = grunt.task.runTaskFn;

grunt.task.runTaskFn = function(context, fn, done, asyncDone) {
    var callback;
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        callback = function (err, success) {
            if (success) {
                resolve();
            } else {
                reject(err);
            }
            return done.apply(this, arguments);
        };
    });

    something.trigger("new task", context.name, context.nameArgs, promise);

    return old_runTaskFn.call(this, context, fn, callback, asyncDone);
}
```

You can use callback + function instead of promise + trigger. This function will request the new callback wrapper for new task.